# Uncaught Reference Error with inline javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
if ($(this).find('#sel').length == 0) {
    var before = $(this).text();
    var title_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).html("<select id='sel' onchange='selectdone(this, title_id=title_id)>
                   ...</select>");
}
```

From this I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: title_id is not defined`. Why isn't the `onchange` function inside on line 4 not picking up on the variable that I've defined previously? How would I rewrite the above correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
$(this).html("<select id='sel' onchange='selectdone(this, "+title_id+");'>...</select>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation here:

```
$(this).html("<select id='sel' onchange='selectdone(this, title_id=" + title_id +");'>...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you're defining the "change" handler as part of a string, so the language has no idea that there's code in there.

Try this:

```
$(this).html($("<select/>", {
  id: 'sel',
  change: function() { selectdone(this, title_id) }
}));
```

Since you're using jQuery anyway, you should get in the habit of managing your event handlers via the library instead of with "onfoo" attributes.